# Question concerning chain rule for multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, chain-rule

I'm working with a two 2-variable-functions that depend on $x$ (called $R$ and $r$) and I'm trying to figure out what $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is. My book gives the following answer: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}}$. I know how the chain rule works, but I would like to see a proof concerning this relation.

Comment: Don't you think it is a good idea to post the function?

Comment: Be very careful. $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not the same as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. The first one is full derivative, the second is partial. Please be very precise in your writing above

Comment: I'm not worried about how to calculate those derivatives, I'm asking why the equation I wrote holds

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between full and partial derivatives? The above relationship you wrote is the chain rule

Comment: I know the difference between a total and a partial derivative, but in the problem I was working with I was asked to derive the "components" of a gradient, that's why I'm using partial derivatives

Comment: Why don't you write $\frac{d}{dx}$ as a total derivative?

Comment: Don't you think it is a good idea to post the function?

Comment: @callculus no I don't think it is